# 14.10 doesn't boot

Tags: boot, 14.10, crash

My approximately 2 months old installation of 14.10 stopped working properly today.
I installed updates yesterday, I think there was a new Kernel too - restarted normally yesterday.

But today it's taking unusual long to take me to the login screen, after logging in the loading process seems to stop. Also the resolution is kind of messed up and only my primary monitor gets a signal.
Sometimes I get problem reports alá "problem deteced" without any given information, once cinnamon stopped working and I also had an error with "upowerd" (or similar spelling, "opowered" or something) at the first occurrence.

I tried bootin with an older Kernel and using unity, nothing helped.

Thank you in advance for your tips! As I am still very new to the Linux world I can't figure it out myself.

Comment: News: I figured it out! Somehow the last updates killed my xserver, it wasn't usable properly. I run nvidia-xserver and it wrote me a new x-file, restarted and it worked.

Comment: could you please copy this comment into the answer box below?  (and detail the exact commands you used) that way: 1/ bozo's like me hunting for unanswered questions will not see an unanswered question any more.  2/ Other users having the same problem, can find your answer and use it and upvote it! ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: As the visual issues I had pointed to a graphic driver problem, I used

- sudo nvidia-xconfig

to create a new xserver config file. After a reboot everything was fine.
Probably due to the updates no proper working driver was used or something.